# adding row dynamically into the table is not working using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add this into a table but wen i click the add button 2 rows are adding simulataneously i mean loops running twice. But no problem with remove row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_partners_details").click(function() {
    var newrow = $('<div class="t-row"><div class="t-col"><input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_sl_no_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/></div><div class="t-col"><input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_pin_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/></div><div class="t-col end"><input type="text" class="text_field required txtAlphabet" name="partners_or_directors_name_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/></div><div class="t-col border_none"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_partners_details">Remove</a></div></div>');
        $("#details_of_partners_directors").append(newrow);
    });

    $("#details_of_partners_directors").on('click','.remove_partners_details',function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="t-row">
    <div class="t-col">
         <input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric"name="partners_or_directors_sl_no_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="t-col">
         <input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_pin_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="t-col end">
         <input type="text" class="text_field required txtAlphabet" name="partners_or_directors_name_id[]" value="" placeholder=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="t-col border_none">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_partners_details">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no element with id `details_of_partners_directors`

Comment: Possible duplicate of this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/3AJcj/2/ if not post a fiddle of ur code..

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9ta6D/1/

Comment: "name" is not "id". So you try to reach undefined DOM Object(espacially undefined ID).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening because you are using a class selector which is causing the click event to fire for each element that has that class. Try using a unique class name or id.

Comment: "details_of_partners_directors" is the table name.

Comment: name is not id i know.. but for our identification we have given like "name_id".

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I'm seeing since you are using effect(), you need to include the jQuery UI library also

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MzjCNm1xIOpDK1yHbvt?p=preview)

Comment: setup jsfiddle for the same.

Comment: This might help @Supriya

Comment: Sorry i had included jquery file, in which i had written the jquery code, twice.. so the loop was running twice.. and thanku for everyone who responded..

Answer (score 0):

I had done some work please check

**Jquery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".add_partners_details").click(function () {
            var curindex = parseInt($("#hdn").val(), 10);
            if (curindex == 0) {
                curindex = 1;
            }
            else {
                curindex = curindex + 1;
            }

            var newDiv = '<div class="t-row" id= parentDiv' + curindex + '>' +
    '<div class="t-col">' +
                '<input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_sl_no_id[]"' +
            'value="" placeholder="" /></div>' +
    '<div class="t-col">' +
        '<input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_pin_id[]" value="" placeholder="" /></div>' +
    '<div class="t-col end" id="last">' +
        '<input type="text" class="text_field required txtAlphabet" name="partners_or_directors_name_id[]" value="" placeholder="" /></div>' +
    '<div class="t-col border_none">' +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_partners_details">Add</a>' +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Remove_partners_details">Remove</a>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
            var prediv = $('#hdnParent').val();
            $("#" + prediv).after(newDiv);
            $("#hdn").val(curindex);
            $('#hdnParent').val('parentDiv' + curindex);

        });

        $(".Remove_partners_details").click(function () {

            var curindex = parseInt($("#hdn").val(), 10);
            if (curindex != 0)
                $("#" + $('#hdnParent').val()).remove();
            if (curindex >= 1) {
                $("#" + curindex).remove();
                if (curindex == 1) {
                    curindex = 0;
                }
                else {
                    curindex = curindex - 1;
                }
                if (curindex == 0) {
                    $('#hdnParent').val('parentDiv');

                }
                else {
                    $('#hdnParent').val('parentDiv' + curindex);

                }
                $("#hdn").val(curindex);
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

**ASPX:**

```
   <div class="t-row" id="parentDiv">
    <div class="t-col">
        <input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric"   name="partners_or_directors_sl_no_id[]"
            value="" placeholder="" /></div>
    <div class="t-col">
        <input type="text" class="text_field txtNumeric" name="partners_or_directors_pin_id[]"
            value="" placeholder="" /></div>
    <div class="t-col end" id="last">
        <input type="text" class="text_field required txtAlphabet" name="partners_or_directors_name_id[]"
            value="" placeholder="" /></div>
    <div class="t-col border_none">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_partners_details">Add</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Remove_partners_details">Remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="0"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="hdnParent" value="parentDiv"/>
```

it is working fine on my end. Now you have to add only logic for hide and display remove and add button. As you for dynamic controls you have to fire events using http://api.jquery.com/live/ . please do this as i have some time limitation.

Hope this will help you.Please update for further assistance.